# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Database\User.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, read-write

i have a problem with my code, the **User.txt** file does exist, and i tried to catch the exception, but this error always keeps on showing after i call the **readUser** function. this is my code, please help me if you can, thank you

```
private static void readUser_(String fileName)
{
    obj_User = null;
    countUser_ = 0;
    VectorClear_(V_User);
    obj_User = new User[countObjectQuantity_(fileName)];
    try {

            File file = new File(fileName);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
            {
                String inputLine = scanner.nextLine();
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inputLine,DELIMITERS_);

                Vector<String>  temp= new Vector();
                VectorClear_(temp);
                while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                { temp.addElement(st.nextToken()); }
                if(temp.size() == 0) return;

                String id            = temp.elementAt(0);
                String password      = temp.elementAt(1);
                String status        = temp.elementAt(2);
                String contactNumber = temp.elementAt(3);
                String firstName     = temp.elementAt(4);
                String lastName      = temp.elementAt(5);
                String email         = temp.elementAt(6);

                if(status.compareToIgnoreCase("admin")==0 )
                {

                    //String adminLevel = temp.elementAt(7);
                    String staffId    = temp.elementAt(7);
                    String staffIcNo  = temp.elementAt(8);

                    obj_User[countUser_] = new Admin(id,password,contactNumber,firstName,lastName,email,/*adminLevel,*/staffId,staffIcNo);
                    V_User.addElement(obj_User[countUser_]);

                    countUser_++;
                }
                else if(status.compareToIgnoreCase("customer")==0 )
                {
                    String gender       = temp.elementAt(7);
                    Date dateOfBirth    = convertStringToDate( temp.elementAt(8));
                    String address      = temp.elementAt(9);

                    obj_User[countUser_] = new Customer(id,password,contactNumber,firstName,lastName,email,gender,dateOfBirth,address);
                    V_User.addElement(obj_User[countUser_]);

                    countUser_++;
                }

            }

            scanner.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some more of your code? E.g., the call that actually throws the exception? Also, a complete stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: this seems to be incomplete info. Please put some more info.

Comment: i have put the code of the function in the edited post

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means there is no directory

**Database** in your working directory,

or if it exists, there is no file **User.txt** in it.

You need to check what your working directory is for your program (at runtime) 
and see if this directory and this file exist. Apparently it does not find them.

Add this print out in your program and see what your working directory is.
`System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

For more details you may want to check these pages.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: well, you are right, there's no directory Database in the working directory. can you please tell me how can i put it in the path. thank you

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi Just create it, and copy your User.txt file in it. Or if User.txt currently exists elsewhere of your disk, make your program read User.txt from the correct location and not from this one.

Answer (score 1):

If the path you are trying to use is Database\User.txt as mentioned in the question, then using the forward slash ('/') instead of the backward slash ('\') should solve the problem.

So the path is Database/User.txt. This is because the backward slash is a special character in java and should be escaped if you must use it (ie, place another backward slash in front of it).

Comment: This is of course assuming that the folder Database is in your classpath and the file User.txt does exist.